# How to create big sized .txt file?

Tags: c#, .net

For certain reasons, I have to create a 1024 kb .txt file.

Below is my current code:

```
int size = 1024000 //1024 kb..


byte[] bytearray = new byte[size];
foreach (byte bit in bytearray) 
{
     bit = 0;
}


string tobewritten = string.Empty;
foreach (byte bit in bytearray) 
{
     tobewritten += bit.ToString();
}


//newPath is local directory, where I store the created file
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(newPath))
{
     sw.WriteLine(tobewritten);
}
```

I have to wait at least 30 minutes to execute this piece of code, which I consider too long.

Now, I would like to ask for advice on how to actually achieve my mentioned objective effectively. Are there any alternatives to do this task? Am I writing bad code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `byte bit` ... that's just wrong.

Comment: Is it? I was actually writing the code in VB.NET, and I use online conversion tool. The byte bit thingy is working fine here...

Comment: On a side note, isn't 1024kb 1,048,576 bytes?  (1024 x 1024)

Comment: Hmm.. haha.. I got it wrongly.. thx...

Comment: Variable names matter! +1 for "bytes aren't bits".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new file with specific size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416413/create-new-file-with-specific-size)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several misunderstandings in the code you provided:

```
byte[] bytearray = new byte[size];
foreach (byte bit in bytearray) 
{
     bit = 0;
}
```

You seem to think that your are initializing each byte in your array `bytearray` with zero. Instead you just set the loop variable `bit` (unfortunate naming) to zero `size` times. Actually this code wouldn't even compile since you *cannot* assign to the foreach iteration variable.

Also you didn't need initialization here in the first place: byte array elements are automatically initialized to 0.

```
string tobewritten = string.Empty;
foreach (byte bit in bytearray) 
{
     tobewritten += bit.ToString();
}
```

You want to combine the string representation of each byte in your array to the string variable `tobewritten`. Since strings are immutable you create a *new* string for each element that has to be garbage collected along with the string you created for `bit`, this is relatively expensive, especially when you create **2048000** one of them - use a `Stringbuilder` instead.

Lastly all of that is not needed at all anyway - it seems you just want to write a bunch of "0" characters to a text file - if you are not worried about creating a single large string of zeros  (it depends on the value of `size` whether this makes sense) you can [just create the string directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) to do this one go - or alternatively write a smaller string directly to the stream a bunch of times.

```
using (var file = File.CreateText(newpath))
{
    file.WriteLine(new string('0', size));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace the string with a pre-sized `StringBuilder` to avoid unnecessary allocations.

Or, better yet, write each piece directly to the `StreamWriter` instead of pointlessly building a 100MB in-memory string first.

Comment: +1  To understand *why* see the "Performance Considerations" here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.100).aspx) and this very technical article by Joel Spolsky (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)