# C# equivalent of numpy memmap to create big file

Tags: c#

I would like to migrate my code from python to C#.

At some in my python code I use [np.memmap](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to create a really big empty image on my disk.

An example is show here:

```
out_full_size = np.memmap("test.rgb", dtype=np.uint8, mode='w+', shape=(100000,100000, 3))
```

This code create a big image of empty pixels directly on the disk in a matter of seconds. Image that I would fill chunk by chunk.

I would like to know if there is any C# function which allow to do this ? I saw in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=net-6.0) that it is possible to access a large file without loading it entirely but not to create one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new file with specific size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416413/create-new-file-with-specific-size)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file with [File.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=net-6.0).

To create a memory-mapped view of part of it, you can use [MemoryMappedFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=netstandard-2.0).

Comment: Your answer could be better if you add actual code examples instead of just links to docs.